# How to get entity keys(parent and custom name) in datastore using python3

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have an entity like this below..

```
 Name/ID                   Parent                    Rollen               email          first_name      last_name
name=CidassUID  Key(Tenant, 'CidassGroupID')    ["user","admin"]    user@email.com  user first name user last name
```

Now for example i would like to query data whose email = user@email.com and get the Entity Key(both id and parent).. 
what i am doing write now in python is

```
from google.cloud import datastore
def create_client(project_id):
    return datastore.Client(project_id)
def list_user(client):
    query = client.query(kind='User')
    query.add_filter('email','=','user@email.com')
    l=query.fetch()
    l=list(l)
    print(l)
```

Now it is giving me the response back as

```
[<Entity('Tenant', 'CidassGroupID', 'User', 'CidassUID') {'first_name': 'user first name', 'last_name': 'user last name', 'email': 'user@email.com', 'Rollen': ['user', 'admin']}>]
```

and if i convert it to a dictionary

```
for entity in l:
    a=entity
d=dict(a)
print(d)
```

it shows the ouptut like this and remove the Entity..

```
{'first_name': 'user first name', 'last_name': 'user last name', 'email': 'user@email.com', 'Rollen': ['user', 'admin']}
```

How can i get the Entity keys e.g. ('Tenant', 'CidassGroupID') ('User', 'CidassUID') from this response?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work... I haven't tested it with the actual google api, but it should function the same...

```
d = dict(l[0])
keys = l[0].key.flat_path

new = {keys[i]:keys[i+1] for i in range(0, len(keys), 2)}
d.update(new)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'first_name': 'user first name', 'last_name': 'user last name', 'email': 'user@email.com', 'Rollen': ['user', 'admin'], 'Tenant': 'CidassGroupID', 'User': 'CidassUID'}
```